# Three geographical entities

Tags: geography, knowledge

The following three statements describe a perfectly symmetric relationship 
between certain geographical entities A, B and C.  **What are A, B and C?**

- A borders on all the B except the one named C.
- C borders on all the B except the one named A.
- A and C border on each other.

Comment: So, to be clear, there is a B that is _named_ C, but this is not the same thing as C itself, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A (or C) is Michigan.
C (or A) is Ontario.
B is Great Lakes.

Probably helps that I live about 3 miles from Lake Michigan.

Comment: I was thinking of this, too, but you beat me too it by a few minutes.